# Test failure "Supported source version xxx from annotation processor less than -source 'yyy'" when building TinkerPop

Tags: java, maven, tinkerpop

I am trying to build TinkerPop following this instruction
http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/dev/developer/#building-testing

So cloned a repo, switched to `3.4-dev` branch then ran `mvn clean install`.
This is not the first time for me to do this and last time it succeeded without any issue, but this time I got some tests failing with following mesesages:

```
[ERROR] Failures:
[ERROR]   GremlinDslProcessorTest.shouldCompileAndMovePackage:56 Expected 0 warnings, but found the following 1 warnings:
Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.GremlinDslProcessor' less than -source '13'

[ERROR]   GremlinDslProcessorTest.shouldCompileToDefaultPackage:48 Expected 0 warnings, but found the following 1 warnings:
Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.GremlinDslProcessor' less than -source '13'

[ERROR]   GremlinDslProcessorTest.shouldCompileTraversalAndTraversalSourceToDefaultPackage:66 Expected 0 warnings, but found the following 1 warnings:
Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.GremlinDslProcessor' less than -source '13'

[ERROR]   GremlinDslProcessorTest.shouldCompileWithNoDefaultMethods:74 Expected 0 warnings, but found the following 1 warnings:
Supported source version 'RELEASE_8' from annotation processor 'org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.GremlinDslProcessor' less than -source '13'
```

So somehow my Java setting passes `-source '13'` which is not compatible with the test case. I don't think this is TinkerPop issue but has anyone seen similar issue and know how to fix it ? There are similar questions posted on SO but I could not find a workaround so far.

I am using Java 1.8

```
❯❯❯ java -showversion                                                                                                                                                                                                              ✘ 1 3.4-dev
java version "1.8.0_231"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_231-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

Comment: i see that you have java 1.8 installed but are you sure maven is using that version? perhaps try to do a `mvn --version` to validate that

Comment: how did you solve this issue?